# Cakephp retrieve associated model name/array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I want to retrieve associated model name and their array.
In demo code AssociatedModelName is associated model. 
Demo code is

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )

    [AssociatedModelName] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [field1] => value1
            [field2] => value2
            [field3] => value3
        )
)
```

so how i retrieve this AssociatedModelName model name/array dynamically.Please suggest me appropriate solution.

Comment: you can use `array_map()` function ..

Comment: which 2 parameter pass to array_map function ,one is $this->request->data.another??

Comment: Array_map give me "Array
(
    [submit] => 
    [EffectiveToDate] => 
    [ObjectType] => 
    [CodeConfiguration] => 
    [ObjectAccountConfiguration] => 
    [TaxConfiguration] => 
)"

Comment: no sir it give me same array.. it not work

Comment: i want only associated model which i use in my model only those i want . and i use only 3 model codeconfiguration, objectaccountconfiguration,taxconfiguration.

Comment: You should elaborate a little more detailed what you are trying to do.  What does "dynamically" mean in this context? What should the extracted data structure look like exactly?